# grub-install does not create EFI binary with correct modules

Tags: grub2, uefi, kde-neon

I'm trying to set up full-disk encryption on a KDE Neon system (by, of course, following the [Arch Wiki guides](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system#Encrypted_boot_partition_(GRUB)) [on the subject](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GRUB#Encrypted_/boot)). Some relevant information about the setup:

- The system has two top-level volumes:

  - The EFI System Partition, which is about as normal as an ESP can be
  - A single LUKS2 volume with LVM nested inside it that hosts the whole system, including `/boot`.
- The system is using GRUB 2.06, which includes limited LUKS2 support. The LUKS2 volume is set up to be compatible with this version of GRUB.
- Secure Boot is currently disabled, although may be enabled in the future.

Following the guides, I have a system that works mostly as intended: GRUB asks for the drive password, and if the correct password is entered, finishes its boot sequence and loads the OS, which boots into a usable graphical session.

My only problem is the moment `grub-install` is run (either manually by a user, or, crucially, automatically by `apt` while installing updates to GRUB), the manual EFI binary for GRUB that I have built that supports this setup is overwritten by an EFI binary that does not support this setup (specifically, as mentioned by the latter Arch Wiki article linked above, it does not have the `luks2` module). While I can (and do) have a script that rebuilds and installs the correct GRUB binary, I'd like for `grub-install` to build this binary correctly the first time. Is there some sort of hook I can use to control the EFI binary that is saved to the ESP?

Comment: For what it's worth, I do have a potential (very hacky and not super great) workaround to this problem, but even _that_ isn't working, which is a story for another question...

Comment: Can you elaborate why you need to run `grub-install` frequently in your set-up? Updates to GRUB are rather rare. `update-grub` only changes the configuration, not the binaries.

Comment: @Hermann I do not run it manually or frequently. The issue is with GRUB updates, which while they are infrequent as you say, do happen and are practically guaranteed to render this system unbootable once every ~3-6 months, based on past experience. I'd really rather not forget or skim over a GRUB update and have to haul out a live disk to make it possible to boot into my system again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `dpkg-divert`, you can tell the package management to shift the packaged `grub-install` to a non-standard location:

```
dpkg-divert --local --rename --add /usr/sbin/grub-install
```

This moves `grub-install` to `/usr/sbin/grub-install.divert`, and any time GRUB is updated by package management, the updated file will be placed into the changed location. This would allow you to place a wrapper script into `/usr/sbin/grub-install`.

Assuming that you only need to have `grub-install` invoked with a custom `--modules=` option, the wrapper script could be something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/sbin/grub-install.divert --modules=<your custom set of modules here> "$@"
```

You might also want to submit a "wishlist"-priority bug report to suggest adding a package configuration setting that would allow injecting custom options (or whatever your situation requires) to the automated `grub-install` that will happen with package updates.

If that is ruled as too complex, an alternative might be a package configuration option to disable the automatic run of `grub-install` on package updates. There already exist debconf options `grub2/force_efi_extra_removable` (default=false) and `grub2/update_nvram` (default=true) which both modify the behavior of automatic `grub-install`s, so there is a precedent.

Comment: I was testing out this solution manually, it seems `grub-install` is refusing to include the `luks2` module, even when I explicitly include it in the module list (the rest are included with no issue). I did some more digging and found https://issues.guix.gnu.org/55723#1, which suggests `grub-install` may be deliberately excluding it because it's not considered complete? (In which case...that's fair)

Comment: Actually, using the `-v` flag to `grub-install` I noticed that `grub-install` was using the prebuilt, signed `grubx64.efi` core image, rather than the EFI executable it was creating with `grub-mkimage` under the hood (which correctly included the `luks2` module). Using the `dpkg-divert` + wrapper script method you suggested, I think I should be able to work out a process from here. Thanks!

Comment: If you plan to enable Secure Boot in the future, you should be aware that Secure Boot will prevent GRUB from loading any modules, so you would have to build a `grubx64.efi` with all the modules required for your boot process built in, and then sign it with either your own custom Secure Boot keys (if your system firmware allows such), or with a MOK enabled by `shimx64.efi`. With Secure Boot enabled, the UEFI firmware will just mark any loaded data which cannot be signature checked by the firmware as non-executable in memory. And the FW can only check `.efi` files, not GRUB modules.